# Is an event registered when a monitor comes out of Power Saving Mode?

Tags: windows, power-management, events

I am using task scheduler to fire a program when someone logs in, unlocks the station, and I would like to do it when the screen turns back on prior to locking.   IE the power savings turns off the screen at 5 minutes, lock happens at 15 minutes.

Which event would I register to capture the screen coming back on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GetDevicePowerState sometimes works for monitors. If it's present, you can open the \.\LCD device. Close it immediately after you've finished with it.
>
> Essentially, you're out of luck -- there is no reliable way to detect the monitor power state, short of writing a device driver and filtering all of the power IRPs up and down the display driver chain. And that's not very reliable either.

From a StackOverflow post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203355/is-there-any-way-to-detect-the-monitor-state-in-windows-on-or-off).

Comment: Thanks, I guess i'll have it lock the screen on power off which will force a login prompt and get the same results, thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you followed the link, but there are some other answers and comments that might be useful.